# How to remove null value Strings from Json while converting pojo to Json using Json.toJson() in play framework?

Tags: java, json, playframework, pojo

How can we get result json which don't have null strings when we convert from pojo to json?

```
 class Test{
        public String id;
        public String firstname;
        public String lastname;
        }

        Test test=new Test();
        test.id="1";
        test.firstname="John";
```

When we convert test to json:

```
Json.tojson(test); // using play.libs.Json
```

Result:

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "firstname":"John",
    "lastname":null
    }
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "firstname":"John"
    }
```

Can somebody help with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should annotate your POJO, something like:

```
/**
 * Test class annotate to tell Jackson library to NOT include NULL values.
 */
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Test {
    public String id;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To suppress serializing properties with null values, you can configure the ObjectMapper directly, or make use of the @JsonInclude annotation:

```
 mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

or:

```
 @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
 class Foo
 {
    String bar;
 }
```